# DropDownlistFor with a null-value as default

Tags: asp.net

The code below displays one dropdownlist with categories and an empy textbox for creating a new category. They both "target" the same property and I hope for the following sceanrio:
If the user have not made a selection in the `dropdownlistfor`, then the value in the `textboxfor` should be passed to the controller.

My problem now is that there is always a value selected in the dropdownlist by default. Is there a way to have a default value like this ---Choose Category---, which has a value of null and does not get passed to the controller?

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveCategory", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
                                    {
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            @Html.HiddenFor(o => o.Id)
                                            <p>Choose existing category</p>
                                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ChoosenCategory,
                                                Model.Category.ListOfCategories.Select(kat => new SelectListItem { Text = kat, Value = kat }))
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <p>Create new category</p>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.BlogComment.ComBody, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Add new category" })
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                            <button type="submit" name="xid" class="btn btn-secondary" style="margin-top: 30px;">Save Category</button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style="float: none;clear: both"></div>
                                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set this property to the drop down `-- Select Category --`

Something like this :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ChoosenCategory, Model.Category.ListOfCategories.Select(kat => new SelectListItem { Text = kat, Value = kat }), "-- Select Category --")
```

and let me know if it works for you.